# Google Analytics 4: how to get the name of global object (gtag)

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics Classic/Universal Analytics we could get the name of global object using such code:

```
window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']
```

And then we could get the object by its name:

```
window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']]
```

Looks like in GA4 such approach is not working, I am getting undefined if I try to get this name. Is it possible somehow to get this name in GA4 ?

Also this is my use case: I have a site on which GA4 was added, there is a possibility that the global object - gtag was renamed (but I don't know about that), theafore I need to get current name of the object and then to get the object by its name.

Answer (score 0):

Per the updated [Google Analytics 4 site tag documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/ua/analyticsjs-to-gtagjs), it appears that object may now be in `window.dataLayer`. I'm thinking either:

```
window[window.dataLayer['GoogleAnalyticsObject']]
```

or

```
window.dataLayer['GoogleAnalyticsObject']
```